# A few pages are "hidden" in the Sonos API documentation

Tags: sonos

Some nodes in the Sonos API documentation link to a few other nodes which cannot be accessed, because they return the "403 Forbidden" response:

1) http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/134
links to /node/146

2) http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/407
links to /node/218

3) /node/434 links to /node/110 and /node/218

Please make these 3 pages accessible (/node/110, /node/146, /node/218).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to outdated documentation pages on our side - Thanks for catching it!

The /node/146 page was the old Authentication page, see the updated version here: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/462.
The /node/218 page was the old Custom Error Handling page, see the new and improved Error Handling page here: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/460.
The /node/110 page was the old Standard Error Handling page, see the Error Handling page for details: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/460.